# adding observer to NSArrayController to monitor change of values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have NSArraycontroller with a bind to NSTableView and the values on the NSTableView can be editable. I add a observer to detect when the values of the NSArraycontoller has change value due to the editing.

Here is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(mocDidChangeNotification:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                               object: nil];
```

I can detect when the values had change and I can get the new value but I'm not getting the old value from the notification.

```
- (void)mocDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSLog(@"changes %@", [notification.userInfo valueForKeyPath:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]);

}
```

Console output:

```
changes {(
    <Categories: 0x6000000a27c0> (entity: Categories; id: 0x40000b <x-coredata://3C4A59E5-F730-4DF0-BF7F-CF2A88A2979F/Categories/p1> ; data: {
    category = newCategory;
})
)}
```

Any of you knows how can I track the old value?

I'll really appreciate your help.